Is there a way to find out how many records were updated through Panda's Dataframe.loc?
I am updating some records that match a condition through by using Panda's dataframe.loc.
Is there a way to find out how many records were updated? Example code is as follows:
df.loc[(df['A'] > 20000), ['B','C']] = [10,20]


len(df.loc[(df['A'] > 20000), ['B','C']] = [10,20]) ?

df['A'].gt(20000).sum()?
